# Problems inheriting from a class in the same namespace in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, include, compiler-errors

I was happily working in C++, until compilation time arrived.

I've got several classes inside some namespace (let's call it N); two of these classes correspond to one base class, and other derived from it. Each class has its own pair of .hpp and .cpp files; I think it'd look like:

```
namespace N{

    class Base{
    };

    class Derived: public Base{
    };

}
```

However, g++ (maybe linker) keeps telling me:

```
Derived.hpp:n: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
```

It doesn't recognize Base as a class, even when I have correctly #include'ed the hpp file corresponding to its definition to Derived's .hpp!

"It's something with #includes", I thought, since these classes' .hpps are #included in other files, so I added this to Derived declaration in Derived.hpp:

```
#include "Base.hpp"
namespace N{

    class Base;

    class Derived: public Base{
    };
}
```

And now g++ complains:

```
Derived.hpp:n: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct N::Base’
```

So, I got lost here. Please help me, I will apreciate it a lot. :)

(By the way, I'm rather experienced in Python, not C++, so this issues are really strange to me. Also, I changed classes' names and stuff :).

**Edit:** A more exact representation of my files is:

```
File Pieza.hpp
-----------------------
#include "Celda.hpp"

namespace Reglas
{
    class Pieza
    {    
        public:
        Pieza() {}
        virtual ~Pieza() {}

        private: 
        Celda *c; 
    };
}


File Jugador.hpp
-----------------------
#include "Jugada.hpp" 
#include "Excepciones.hpp"
#include "Pieza.hpp"
namespace Reglas
{  
//compiler asked for these :S
class Celda;
class Tablero;
    class Jugador : public Pieza
    {
        public:
        Jugador() {}
        virtual ~Jugador() {}
    };
}
```

Comment: First, those are compiler errors, not the linker errors. Linker happens after compiling, and you haven't pass that yet. Second, Tell us how your files are organized, are those two classes defined in the same header file? Did you include them properly in the implementation files?

Comment: You are not asking this question the Smart Way.  You post what you think should compile.  We agree, it should.  You are not posting the real content of your header files, there's no way to tell what's wrong with them from your snippets.

Comment: Thank you, I already edited my question.

Comment: Check all your included files for unmatched braces and/or `#ifdef`s. The code you present should compile, so the problem must be  in what you are not showing.

Comment: Are there no other members to Pieza?  If not, then you shouldn't need to include Celda.hpp.  An incomplete type would indicate that the compiler cannot determine the definition of something being used within Pieza.  (Possibly Celda if it is used within Pieza)  Basically...we need more information. =)

Comment: All class definitions (.hpp) are guarded with #ifndef #define #endif.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of information, it's just I'm just too confused with these errors :P. Of course Pieza has a protected member Celda * c; so that's why i needed to include it.

Jugador has no members of these classes, but it has a method that recieves a "Tablero".

Comment: 1) According to this code, Pieze does *not* have a member Celda *c, 2) I have compiled this code without error (if I provide the extra hpp files). We still need more of your code to reproduce the error.

Comment: Then I don't know what is happening. Maybe i'll just give up on this.

Comment: You probably have an error in one of the other headers, which are included before `#include "Pieza.hpp"`. Try to make that header the first one included and see whether the error changes.

Comment: Please don't be discouraged, we are getting close to the answer! Could you show us your Celda.hpp? I think the problem is that Celda is incomplete.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your time, patience and answers. I realize how nice you are, guys. I got all mad and consulted my problems with my pillow for a while, then came back, and solved it. The cause of the problem made me realize also, that my design and patterns are terrible, so I'm going to redesing this anyways. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Derived.hpp:n: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct N::Base’
```

This makes me think that you didn't `#include "Base.hpp` in the `Derived.cpp` source file.

EDIT: In your `Derived.cpp`, try changing the order of `#include`s to:

```
#include "base.hpp"
#include "derived.hpp"

// .. rest of your code ..
```

Like this:

```
// Derived.hpp
#pragma once

namespace foo
{
    class Base;

    class Derived : public Base
    {
    public:
        Derived();

        ~Derived();
    };
}
```

---

```
// Derived.cpp
#include "base.hpp"
#include "derived.hpp"

namespace foo
{
    Derived::Derived()
    {
    }

    Derived::~Derived()
    {
    }
}
```

---

So, you're going to want to edit `Jugador.hpp` to look like this:

```
// Jugador.hpp
#include "Pieza.hpp" // move this above Jugada.hpp
#include "Jugada.hpp" 
#include "Excepciones.hpp"
namespace Reglas
{  
//compiler asked for these :S
class Celda;
class Tablero;
    class Jugador : public Pieza
    {
        public:
        Jugador() {}
        virtual ~Jugador() {}
    };
}
```

Comment: Or the includes are out of order, which is more likely here.

Comment: Ok, I mark your answer as the corect one. A brief explanation: Pieza.hpp contained the definition of class Pieza, which contained a member of class Celda. that's why I included Celda.hpp in Pieza.hpp. However, Class Celda has a member of class Jugador (derived from Pieza!!!), so Celda.hpp includes Jugador.hpp, which itself includes Pieza.hpp (*sigh*). So when the compiler was preprocessing the first includes in Pieza.hpp, it ended up again in Pieza.hpp, before being able to define class Pieza, so Jugador could never inherit from it. So, as you suggested, i #included Celda.hpp in Pieza.cpp.

Answer (score 3):

Your files should look like:

```
File Base.hpp
-----------------------
namespace N
{
    class Base
    {    
        public:
        Base() {}
        virtual ~Base() {}   // Make sure you have a virtual destructor
    };
}


File Derived.hpp
-----------------------
#include "Base.hpp"
namespace N
{  
    class Derived : public Base
    {
        public:
        Derived() {}
        ~Derived() {}
    };
}
```

Comment: No problem - hope my edit summary doesn't come off as condescending. I do that so that non-native speakers can learn from their mistakes rather than having to rely on editors all the time.